# Remove plugin menu pages for certain users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in WordPress custom plugin I'm writing:

```php
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'hide_default_menu_pages') );
    }

    public function hide_default_menu_pages()
    {
        $restricted_users = array(
            'USERONE',
            'USERTWO',
        );
        // Getting the current user 
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        // Getting the current user registered username
        $username = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname', $current_user->ID ); 
        // Checking into the $restricted_users if the current logged user is blacklisted 
        if( in_array( $username, $restricted_users ) ){
            remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );
            remove_menu_page( 'wc-admin' );
        }
    }
```

I want to remove for some users the ability to see the woocommerce pages and elementor pages, but the `remove_menu_page()` function seems not working, I think this will occur because the plugin pages don't really have a slug like the core pages of wordpress but use a querystring like this `admin.php?page=wc-admin` and `admin.php?page=elementor`. How I can achive the desired result?

Comment: You can check url page parameter with $_GET['page']. Keep in mind just removing page from menu wont stop someone to access the page. Thats why we have capabilities for user roles.

Comment: So I just need to pass $_GET['page'] into the `remove_menu_page()` function to achive my scope right? I know about capabilities, but I have three `Administrator` registered but two will not need all other features and I can't directly give them the Editor role.

Comment: Try changing the priority on your `add_action` to something higher/later such as `20`

Comment: I will try and let you know, thanks

Comment: tried to use an high priprity on `add_action` but without success. any other solution I can use?